# How to Add Pagination to a List Custom Query in JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

my repository looks like this:

```
public interface HeroRepository extends JpaRepository<Hero,Long>{
     @Query(value = "SELECT h.heroname , SUM(h.killCount) AS killcount FROM Heroes AS h GROUP BY h.heroname ORDER BY h.heroname",nativeQuery = true)     
     List<IHero> findAllHeroByGroupName();
}
```

How do I add pagination to a custom query that doesnt use the default "findAll" queries by JPA?

How do I tell Spring to convert this to a Page or pageable object?

```
findAllHeroByGroupName()
```

so that in my AppController I can use it like this:

Page page = heroService.findAllHeroByGroupName(pageNum);

Take note, that `findAllHeroByGroupName()` returns a List and not a Page object.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [Pageable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html)

You method in repository class would look like:

```
public interface HeroRepository extends JpaRepository<Hero,Long>{
     @Query(value = "SELECT h.heroname , SUM(h.killCount) AS killcount FROM Heroes AS h GROUP BY h.heroname ORDER BY h.heroname",nativeQuery = true)     
     List<IHero> findAllHeroByGroupName(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Now to fetch the records using Pagination, You can use something like:

```
Pageable firstPageWithTwoElements = PageRequest.of(0, 2);
```

The first argument is pagenumber and second argument is size. You can read more about [PageRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html)

```
List<IHero> allProducts = heroRepository.findAllHeroByGroupName(firstPageWithTwoElements);
```

The `findAll(Pageable pageable)` method by default returns a `Page<T>` object.

However, we can choose to return either a `Page<T>`, a `Slice<T>`, or a `List<T>` from any of our custom methods returning paginated data.

Read more about how to to use Native queries [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_native_queries)

Comment: do you actually know how to create pagination? like actually programmed one?

Comment: if you did, you'd know that List object does not directly translate to Page object which is needed for pagination

Comment: As I said you can either return `List` or `Page`, `Page<IHero> allProducts = heroRepository.findAllHeroByGroupName(firstPageWithTwoElements)`